# What is the command line option to pass into the activator framework to generate an intellij project?

Tags: intellij-idea, typesafe-activator

I'd like to generate the intellij project files from a typesafe activator project via a script - is there a command line interface or command i can use for this purpose?

(i wasn't able to find directions for one online, or in the usual help locations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that since IntelliJ IDEA version 13 it is no longer necessary to generate files for IntelliJ IDEA. sbt support is now build in, you can open/import the project by opening your build.sbt with IntelliJ IDEA: http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2013/11/18/built-in-sbt-support-in-intellij-idea-13/

Comment: when I use that option I am unable to start the play project from IntelliJ

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Activator is just an sbt wrapper with optional UI mode. So what you want is sbt-idea:

https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea

The Activator UI will auto-add this plugin and then (on the Code tab) it has an "open in" menu item to generate the intellij project.

If you want to script it, there are two steps:

1. add the plugin (either drop an `idea.sbt` in `project/` directory or put it globally in `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins`)
2. run `activator gen-idea`

Comment: This isn't really a satisfying answer, as we're being directed from [Play! to activator](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Highlights23), and the Play! CLI included the `idea` command built-in, as well `activator ui` opens a tool that can do the conversion using the [code then Gear icon](https://typesafe.com/activator/docs). What I read you saying is that this "optional ui" mode is actually a requirement for feature parity with the "old" `play` CLI.

Comment: addSbtPlugin the idea plugin globally in .sbt/0.13, then type activator gen-idea (or sbt gen-idea) in any sbt project. There is no UI involved.  You don't even need to do this anymore anyway; just import into IntelliJ http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2013/11/18/built-in-sbt-support-in-intellij-idea-13/

Comment: Well, given the way things move around, Jetbrains claim to import the project seems broken to me. That link is almost a year old, and my experience is that sometimes the sbt-idea plugin works better than IntelliJ's sbt import.